# Is this an assignment operator error?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

So I am getting errors on the following line of code.

```
intVAR = myTYPEvar;
```

where intVAR is an integer and myTYPEvar is a class I made up, but should pass the value of an integer it holds private.  I believe that below operator definition in the .h  is necessary.

```
    public:
       int operator=(const myTYPE & INTin);
```

Its defined in the .cpp as

```
    int myTYPE::operator=(const myTYPE &myTYPEin){
       return (myTYPEin.getprivateint());
     }
```

It will not compile. I believe I am going about this incorrectly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a conversion operator that to be able to write

```
intVAR = myTYPEvar;
```

For example

```
operator int() const { return myTYPEin.getprivateint(); }
```

Take into account that in this case member function getprivateint must be defined with qualifier `const`.

As for your assignment operator then it assigns nothing but the velue of an expresssion where the assignment operator is used has type int. For example using your assignment operator you could write

```
myTYPE obj1, obj2;

int x = obj1 = obj2;
```

In this case the value of call of getprivateint() for obj2 would be assigned to x.

Here is a demonstrative example of what you will have with your assignment operator

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        A( int x ) : x ( x ) {}
        int operator = ( const A & a )
        {
            return a.x;
        }
        int x;
    };

    A a1( 10 ), a2( 20 );
    int x = a1 = a2;

    std::cout << "x = " << x 
              << ", a1.x = " << a1.x 
              << ", a2.x = " << a2.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
x = 20, a1.x = 10, a2.x = 20
```

However you may not write for example

```
x = a1;
```

You need the conversion operator as it is shown above.

Or if to use the example with structure A the code will look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        A( int x ) : x ( x ) {}
        operator int() const { return x; }

        int x;
    };

    A a1( 10 );
    int x = a1;

    std::cout << "x = " << x 
              << ", a1.x = " << a1.x 
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
x = 10, a1.x = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int operator=(const myTYPE & INTin);
```

Such an assigment operator would only allow assignment *to* a `myTYPE` variable, not *from* one.
 What you're looking for might be a conversion operator:

```
operator int() const {
    return (myTYPEin.getprivateint());
}
```